# Laravel(5.4)Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

**Descripción**
días pasados me respondieron en otra pregunta que podría implementar `whereHas` para hacer una consulta a dos tablas diferentes. En este caso a la tabla `noticias` y `notas` misma que no me deja recibir los datos en las vistas de blade.

**Controlador**
Función a implementar. Tira error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) )

¿Cómo se implementaría correctamente la función para que el buscador encuentre resultados de ambas tablas (`notas` y `noticias`), para pasarlas a la vista?

```php
public function busqueda(Request $request){
    $ntc_turno = $request->input('noticiero_turno');
    if ($ntc_turno) {
        Noticia::with('notas')->whereHas(
            'notas',
            function($query) use($ntc_turno) {
                $query->where('nombre_nota','LIKE',"%$ntc_turno%");
            }
        )
        ->orWhere('noticiero_turno','LIKE',"%$ntc_turno%");
        ->orWhere('noticiero_programa','LIKE',"%$ntc_turno%");
        ->orWhere('noticiero_fecha','LIKE',"%$ntc_turno%");
        ->paginate(2);
        return view('noticia.listar',array('noticia'=>$noticia));
    }else {
        $noticia = Noticia::paginate(3);
        return view('noticia.listar',array('noticia'=>$noticia));
    }
}
```

**Modelo: noticia**

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Noticia extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['noticiero_programa','noticiero_turno','noticiero_fecha'];

    public function notas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Nota', 'noticia_id');
    }
}
```

**Modelo: Nota**

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Nota extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['nombre_nota', 'editor_nota','duracion_nota', 'bloque_nota', 'noticia_id'];

    public function noticias()
    {
        return $this->BelongsTo('Noticia', 'noticia_id');
        // pertenece a
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu problema son los ; que sobran al final de cada línea de `orWhere`:

```
->orWhere('noticiero_turno','LIKE',"%$ntc_turno%")
->orWhere('noticiero_programa','LIKE',"%$ntc_turno%")
->orWhere('noticiero_fecha','LIKE',"%$ntc_turno%")
->paginate(2);
```

Comment: Sí era eso,¿Como puedo acceder a los campos nombre_nota de la tabla nota para traerlo a la vista de blade?

Comment: Iteras a través de `$noticia->notas` y simplemente haces `$nota->nombre_nota`